# Call sequential m-files batch file?

Tags: matlab, batch-file

I want to write a batch file that calls sequentially 2 m-files. I want the second m-file (`f.m`) not to start before the end of the first m-file (`main.m`). The second m-file is repeated 4 times (4 tasks).

I have tried to use the wait option as below but it does not work.

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=2G
#$ -l tmem=2G
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y
#$ -N example
#$ -t 1-4
echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"


matlab -wait -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash < main.m

matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash < f.m
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are `main.m` and `f.m` scripts or functions?

Comment: They are both scripts. `main.m` creates some matrices and save them. `f.m` loads the matrices and calls a function that contains the SGE_TASK_ID.

Comment: Seems you are confusing [tag:bash] and [tag:batch-file]; please read the tag info and update tha tags accordingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either concatenate the contents of `main.m` and `f.m` together prior to piping them to MATLAB

```
cat main.m f.m | matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash
```

Or you can call the scripts by passing a command to MATLAB using the `-r` flag

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r 'main; f; exit'
```

These are both going to be more performant than your approach since here we're only launching one instance of MATLAB.

Comment: Any difference in terms of efficiency or other between the two options?

Comment: @user3285148 Should not really be a difference between the two at all. The second approach is the more MATLAB-based approach. The first is a *nix-based approach